# Python cos(90) and cos(270) not 0

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

What is going on??

Testing out sin and cos functions to find out why I get so beautiful positioning on the wrong places when outputting my coordinates into a SVG file. So I made this test code, which I can predict what the answer is to find out why. Oddly nothing that effects the calculation it self adds this behavior but simply the position of where I'm about to stay. If the position is 0 and will become 0 after the calculation it won't work, but if position is 1 and will become 1 after the calculation it works.

First Test:

```
import math

cX = 2
cY = 2
r = 2

rcX = cX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(0)))
rcY = cY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(0)))

print rcX #4
print rcY #2
r = 1

rlX = rcX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(90)))
rlY = rcY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(90)))

print rlX #4
print rlY #3
r = 4

flX = rlX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(180)))
flY = rlY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(180)))

print flX #0
print flY #3
r = 2

print r * math.cos(math.radians(270))
print flX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(270))) #-3.67394039744e-16 should be 0
print flY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(270))) #1
```

Now I change cX to 3 and it works even if it doesn't effect the calculation which is:

```
r * math.cos(math.radians(270))
```

The result of that calculation is added to the x coordination

```
import math

cX = 3
cY = 2
r = 2

rcX = cX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(0)))
rcY = cY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(0)))

print rcX #5
print rcY #2
r = 1

rlX = rcX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(90)))
rlY = rcY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(90)))

print rlX #5
print rlY #3
r = 4

flX = rlX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(180)))
flY = rlY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(180)))

print flX #1
print flY #3
r = 2

print r * math.cos(math.radians(270))
print flX + (r * math.cos(math.radians(270))) #1
print flY + (r * math.sin(math.radians(270))) #1
```

Comment: `-3.67394039744e-16` is close enough no?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: You're aware that the conversion to radians suffers from rounding errors, are you?

Comment: You want to learn yourself some floating point error.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Computers try to represent an infinite range of floating point numbers using a finite number of binary digits. This leads to issues well-described in Goldberg's paper mentioned by desimusxvil. It also leads to this parable in computer science: "1 + 1 equals 3 for sufficiently large values of 1."

Comment: @commenters: could you please post links to rounding errors in rad conversions and floating point errors. They might help OP a lot

Comment: @legends2k It does, twice, and the rounding errors cancel. When you convert 90.0 degrees to radians, you get `π/2 ± ε`, and `sin (π/2 ± ε)` is roughly `1 - ε²/2`. Now, `ε` is on the order of 1e-16, so `1 - ε²/2` is rounded to 1.0. but `cos (π/2 ± ε)` is roughly `±ε`. The function has no way of knowing whether the argument it received was meant to be `π/2` or not. So a good implementation gives you the closest representable to the mathematical value of the cosine of the argument.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, it is a very low number, awfully close to zero.  Here's a great article which can help you understand the common challenges and pitfalls of floats: "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)"

Answer (score 6):

You are dealing with rounding errors, which are (mostly) unavoidable when working with floating point math (see the [paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) already linked by others to understand exactly what's going on).

In many cases you can reduce their impact (by performing the operations in "intelligent" order or reformulating your expressions in a more "floating point-friendly" way), but the simplest thing to do in your situation is to round the results to e.g. 6 decimal places and be happy with it. Surely you won't need more precision in positioning, and you'll get the results you expect for the "canonical" angles.

Comment: I don't see how this couldn't be in the function to begin with? Haven't read the whole paper yet looks interesting.

Comment: `cos` doesn't know if it's argument is 7/4pi affected by rounding error or if you intentionally passed that "slightly wrong" value, it just tries to give you the cosine of the argument it received. You can always round the return value after its evaluation, but you couldn't get the precision back if it rounded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had to work with cos, sin, and tan of 270 degrees for a project today. I wouldn't have known there was an error if I didn't google the results to check myself.
(I know making the degrees a constant for no reason just turn it into a radian is ridiculous, it's what they wanted for the project.)

cos and sin were working for me as long as I rounded the radian first, but tan was way off.

I fixed the tangent by doing the math manually and catching the error of not being able to divide by 0 and setting it to Undefined:

```
    #variables for various trigonometric functions (sine, cosine and tangent) of 270 degrees
    DEGREE = 270
    RADIAN = round(m.radians(DEGREE), 3) #the degree has to be converted to a radian to input into the math.cos and math.sin functions
    COS = round(m.cos(RADIAN), 2) #pass the radian to get the cosine
    SIN = round(m.sin(RADIAN), 2) #pass the radian to get the sine

    try:
         # the math library did not return the correct answer for tangent when dividing by 0
         # so, I manually did the math, this catches the division by zero and correctly labels the tangent
         # as undefined
        tan = round(SIN/COS, 2)
        
    except:
        tan = "Undefined"

    print("\n\nMathematical Constants") #display a title for the list

    #headers list for each function
    headers = ["Pi", "e", "Sine(270\u00b0)", "Cosine(270\u00b0)", "Tangent(270\u00b0)"]
    #list of each constant
    dataList = [round(m.pi, 2), round(m.e, 2), SIN, COS , tan]

    #looping iterator to diplay each function
    i = 0
    while i < len(headers):
        print("------")
        print(headers[i] + ": " + str(dataList[i]))

        i += 1 #increase iterator by one
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30823206)