# Why does .NET Math.Cos() return a wrong answer for pi/2?

Tags: c#, .net, math, trigonometry

I have a method to convert degrees to radians...

```
public static double ToRadians(double degAngle) 
{
    return Math.PI * degAngle / 180;
}
```

...and it works pretty well.
But when I try 
`Math.Cos(ToRadians(90));`, it returns 6.12303176911189E-17. Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you noticed the `E-17`? That's because of the rounding. The floatingpoint doesn't not have an endless precision.

Comment: What is the expected value? How far off is it? Is it within expected float inprecision? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: The expected value of `cos(90 degrees)` is `0` (cosine is the X component of the unit-circle, which at ninety degrees is zero).  The answer you're getting is due to floating point precision errors.  6E-17 is very close to zero.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: It is the expected result based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cos?view=netframework-4.8)   same thing happens in [other language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260296/python-cos90-and-cos270-not-0). I would assume that you can never pass degree 90 to that method since it would need to much precision in radian as parameter.

Comment: Indeed it's right there in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cos?view=netframework-4.8#examples): `Math.Cos(90 deg) == 6.1230317691118863E-017`.  Perhaps [How to check if Math.cos(angle) = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28700168/3744182) or [Accuracy of Math.Sin() and Math.Cos() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3249710/3744182) answer your question.

Comment: I got `1.57079632679` but not using that...

Comment: @AllisonE I use `var r = Math.Acos(ToRadians(-0.0));` `-0.0` represents 90 degrees which outputs `1.5707963267948966` half...

Answer (score 1):

It's not because you aren't passing pi/2 as a parameter but something close to it.

Math.PI * 90 / 180 will not return the exact radian for degree 90, only something very close since Math.PI doesn't have infinite precision. To get an exact value of 0 returned by Math.Cos, you would need the pass the exact value in radian. You can only get a value very close to zero. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cos?view=netframework-4.8) show this is the proper value.

Comment: I am still getting the same answer. Or did I use the wrong value? Is the exact value of 90 degrees not `1.5707963267948966192313216916916398... ` in radian?

Comment: @AllisonE you can't get an exact value in radian for 90 degree. Only something very close like in your comment. That's why the result is something very close to zero.

Comment: @AllisonE It would take infinite digits to perfectly represent 90 degrees in radians, because PI is itself transcendental.

Answer (score 1):

90 degrees is *approximately* `1.5707963267948966...` radians.  I say "approximately" because PI is a transcendental number, but in double-precision floating point values, we are limited to 64-bits.  That means the resulting calculation will be off by some margin of error.  That same error occurs again when you take the cosine (a transcendental function).  The resulting value cannot be perfectly represented in double-precision, so you receive an approximation.  The correct answer is zero.  The answer you have is `0.00000000000000061230317691118863`, which is *very* close to zero.

If you were to do this math by hand, using `3.14` as the value of PI, you will get an answer that is close to, but not exactly, zero, for the same reason: you are using approximations.  Using `3.1415926` will give you a closer answer, but that value of PI is still an approximation.  The computer is using another approximation, one limited to 64-bits of precision, which comes out to roughly 16 digits of PI.

This issue will occur in any computing system that uses IEEE-754 floating point math. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more info.

Also take a look at [this blog post](https://www.exploringbinary.com/pi-and-e-in-binary/), which goes into greater detail in how PI is represented in computers.